# Click element is not working in Appium, 'java.lang.NullPointerException' occurring

Tags: selenium, appium, mobile-application, appium-android

Eclipse Console Error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebElement.execute(RemoteWebElement.java:279)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebElement.click(RemoteWebElement.java:83)
    at amazon.StartApplication.main(StartApplication.java:58)
```

Appium log:

```
    {"strategy":"id","selector":"in.amazon.mShop.android.shopping:id/sign_in_button","context":"","multiple":false}}
    [debug] [AndroidBootstrap] [BOOTSTRAP LOG] [debug] Got data from client: {"cmd":"action","action":"find","params":{"strategy":"id","selector":"in.amazon.mShop.android.shopping:id/sign_in_button","context":"","multiple":false}}
    [debug] [AndroidBootstrap] [BOOTSTRAP LOG] [debug] Got command of type ACTION
    [debug] [AndroidBootstrap] [BOOTSTRAP LOG] [debug] Got command action: find
    [debug] [AndroidBootstrap] [BOOTSTRAP LOG] [debug] Finding 'in.amazon.mShop.android.shopping:id/sign_in_button' using 'ID' with the contextId: '' multiple: false
    [debug] [AndroidBootstrap] [BOOTSTRAP LOG] [debug] Using: UiSelector[INSTANCE=0, RESOURCE_ID=in.amazon.mShop.android.shopping:id/sign_in_button]
    [debug] [AndroidBootstrap] [BOOTSTRAP LOG] [debug] Returning result: {"status":0,"value":{"ELEMENT":"2"}}
    [debug] [AndroidBootstrap] Received command result from bootstrap
    [debug] [MJSONWP] Responding to client with driver.findElement() result: {"ELEMENT":"2"}
    [info] [HTTP] <-- POST /wd/hub/session/fb4c547d-3a81-4b48-b6ff-cb14eb629138/element 200 28 ms - 87
```

Waited 60 seconds:

```
waited 60 seconds for a command
[debug] [AndroidDriver] Shutting down Android driver
```

Appium server is shutting down after the 1 minute

Comment: Have you tried xpath ... ?

Comment: first of all increase the waittimeout and post more logs

Comment: @SaurabhVerma: Yes, I have, but the Click is not working here the click command is not executed **"driver.findElementByXPath("//*[@text='Already a customer? Sign in']").click();"**  Null pointer exception occurred after this line of code

Comment: it might be possible that the driver instance that you are using turns null at some point of code. Try debugging the code. I faced this problem many times. Hope that helps

Comment: @SaurabhVerma, Could you please let know in detail? You mean the Appium server URL needs to be changed? How do we find the element we given in the code is accessible by the appium server

Answer (score 0):

The default appium new command timeout value is 60 seconds, that's why appium server is shutting down the driver after 60 seconds. You can change the default timeout by setting in the capabilities as below:

```
capabilities.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.NEW_COMMAND_TIMEOUT, 6000);
```

or

```
capabilities.setCapability("newCommandTimeout", 6000);
```

Comment: actually the click command is not executed **"driver.findElementByXPath("//*[@text='Already a customer? Sign in']").click();"**  Null pointer exception occurred after this line of code

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, `NullPointerException` in Java only occurs when the object it's referring to is `null`.

So it's possible that the variable you are using in this case is `null` and you are performing some calls on it, e.g.:

```
element.click ();
```

Here, element may be `null`.

So you need to handle this situation gracefully. If element is `null`, don't go to click on it, instead, log the error and exit.